# How to emulate press Enter key with Zombie.js

Tags: javascript, zombie.js

Do you know how to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key with Zombie.js ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that yet using just zombie API. It's because `.fire()` method doesn't allow you to pass any event data in addition to event name (which would be necessary to *state* which keyCode is associated with that key event).

Answer (score 0):

WTK is correct and there's no native way in zombie.js but I think you could add a javascript function to simulate the enter key press and trigger it from zombie.js like so:

If you have access to the page source, add a function on your page to simulate the enter key press:

```
function pressEnterKey(elmSelector){
  elmSelector = elmSelector || 'document'
  var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
  e.which = 13; 
  e.keyCode = 13;
  $(elmSelector).trigger(e);
}
```

Trigger it from zombie.js:

```
browser.evaluate("pressEnterKey()");
```

If you don't have access to the source you could inject the script on the page using something like this. Remember to use browser.wait after to ensure the page is ready:

```
var injectedScript = browser.document.createElement("script");
injectedScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
injectedScript.innerText = '...pressEnterKey function text here...'
browser.body.appendChild(injectedScript);
```